# AWS EC2 with Elastic Load balancer not sending SSL Certificate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a server that is sending an HTTPPost request with the Apache HttpClient in Java.  I am trying to send the post with my cert attached for validation and the other side is saying they are not receiving anything SSL information.  I inherited this code/server setup with minimal documentation so I don't necessarily know it was set up properly in the first place.

Here is the setup.

1. AWS EC2 server. Linux
2. Elastic Load balancer setup with SSL Cert.
   a. Verified this is working as intended when I visit the server via port 443
3. Tomcat7 running API server
4. Java 1.8.0_251
5. Apache httpclient-4.5.9

Being that there are ways to attach the certificate to each level of this I don't fully understand where the problem is.

Most of the ways I have found revolve around attaching the SSL to the outgoing request in the httpclient object but have been unsuccessful.  They are a variation on the following...

```
KeyStore identityKeyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            identityKeyStore.load(identity_file, CERTPASSWORD.toCharArray());

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(identityKeyStore, CERTPASSWORD.toCharArray()).build(); // load client certificate

            sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslContext,
                    new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"},
                    null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
```

This has not worked and I have verified the .jks file is properly formatted and verified the password.  Although if this works as I test on a windows machine I would assume this would be the best option.

This server only has outgoing requests to a few sources all of which will need to be SSL verified so I don't mind if it is sent on every outgoing https request.

Is there somewhere else in my setup that I should be looking into attaching the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a Load balancer with SSL configured then the SSL stops at the load balancer, and your client certificate is never making it to the server. Client SSL certificates only get passed to the server when the server has an SSL certificate installed on it, and the load balancer is in TCP passthrough mode.

Comment: So just to make sure im understanding properly my load balancer on my EC2 is stopping the outgoing Cert to the vendor server im trying to communicate with?  or the load balancer is stopping the response coming back from the vendor? To fix this i would remove the cert from the load balancer and install it directly on the EC2 image?

Comment: No sorry, I thought you were submitting your cert to a server that was behind a load balancer. If your EC2 server is submitting a request, the fact that your EC2 server is registered with a load balancer is not relevant. The Load balancer does not participate in outbound requests initiated by the EC2 server.